# gulp-typings - Issues with Beautylog

Tags: npm, gulp, typescript-typings

Up until today we were having no problems but in our typescript solution it appears a dependency of gulp-typings is having issues with an update to dependency beautylog?  I have tried installing/uninstalling gulp-typings and beautylog to no success.  Anyone have any thoughts or seen this yet?

```
Failed to run "C:\xxxx\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
C:xxxx\node_modules\beautylog\dist\beautylog.classes.table.js:3
const plugins = require("./beautylog.plugins");
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxxx\node_modules\beautylog\dist\index.js:4:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following link

[Pull Request To Fix Problem](https://github.com/typings/gulp-typings/pull/16)

Bottom line upgrade to 2.0.3 for gulp-typings if you are still using node < 6

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this too. Found this

https://gitlab.com/pushrocks/beautylog/issues/7

Comment: Good find I think the author is being unreasonable about breaking support though.